# date range is not consder in mysql

Tags: mysql

my select query is like this i have records in my "processbackup"  table in this date range but still it's not considering date range in result i get zero rows.

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(processDate,'%d-%m-%Y') AS processDate,
    DATE_FORMAT(rDate,'%d-%m-%Y') AS rDate,
    designMaster.dNo,
    processbackup.desWet,
    reciveWet,
    item.itemNm,
    processbackup.workerId
  FROM processbackup 
  LEFT JOIN designMaster
    ON designMaster.designMasterId = processbackup.designMasterId 
  LEFT JOIN item AS i
    ON i.itemId = designMaster.itemId
  LEFT JOIN item
    ON item.itemId = designMaster.itemId
 WHERE processbackup.workerId = 1
   AND (processDate BETWEEN '2015-04-04' AND '2015-04-14')
```

Comment: Do you get any results if you remove the restriction on processDate?

Comment: Two questions: What data type is processDate?  Do you get any results if you change your range to 2015-04-01 through 2015-04-30?

Comment: date datatype no i dont get any result if me change date @MarkLeiber

Comment: Something isn't adding up.  What is the result of SELECT count(*) FROM processbackup LEFT JOIN designMaster ON designMaster.designMasterId = processbackup.designMasterId LEFT JOIN item AS i ON i.itemId = designMaster.itemId LEFT JOIN item ON item.itemId = designMaster.itemId WHERE processbackup.workerId = 1;

Comment: it's give me result 2 @MarkLeiber

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75518/discussion-between-mark-leiber-and-user1866385).

Comment: As discussed in our chat, the processDate values in your database are in 2016, so change your query to "AND (processDate BETWEEN '2016-04-04' AND '2016-04-14')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your query.

Run it as:

```
SELECT processDate 
  FROM processbackup 
  LEFT JOIN designMaster
    ON designMaster.designMasterId = processbackup.designMasterId 
  LEFT JOIN item AS i
    ON i.itemId = designMaster.itemId
  LEFT JOIN item
    ON item.itemId = designMaster.itemId
 WHERE processbackup.workerId = 1
   AND (processDate BETWEEN '2015-04-04' AND '2015-04-14')
```

Look at the dates returned.  If they are not between 2015-04-04 and 2015-04-14, you'll get no results.

Note that if processDate is a a datetime, your results won't include values from 2015-04-14.  You'll need to include a time in your WHERE clause or change it to 2015-04-15.

Answer (score 0):

you should put processDate into HAVING clause, not in WHERE, because your value is calculated from select.

Comment: please provide your data set and schema